# Cannot make a successful pass in travis-ci for my C++ app

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, travis-ci

I am working on [this project](http://github.com/noise2/quadrotor-sim) an it compiles fine in my desktop using `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4` and `cmake version 2.8.12.2`.

I am new in travis-ci thing, I have wrote a `.travis.yml` script as follow

```
language: cpp

compiler:
  - g++

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
    - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
    - gcc-4.8
    - g++-4.8
    - libboost-all-dev
    - cmake

install:
- if [ "$CXX" = "g++" ]; then export CXX="g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/boost -DENABLE_REINFORCEMENT_LEARNING" CC="gcc-4.8"; fi

before_script:
  - mkdir build
  - cd build
  - cmake ..

script: make
```

My project has `boost` library dependency.
My problem is the travis-ci indicates compiler error in my `timer` variable.

```
#include "stdafx.hpp"
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include "timer.hpp"
#include "configs.hpp"
#include "incurses.hpp"
#include "quadrotor.hpp"
#include "main.helper.hpp"
#include "main.output.hpp"

#ifdef ENABLE_REINFORCEMENT_LEARNING
#   include "RLearner.Sarsa.hpp"
#endif

volatile bool
    sig_ctrl_c = false;

std::mutex log_lock;

> timer screener; <
// /home/travis/build/noise2/quadrotor-sim/main.cpp:27:1: error: ‘timer’ does not name a type
// timer screener;
scalar iter_simulation              = 0;
const size_t max_iter_simulation    = 1e+5;
```

You can see the travis-ci result [here](https://travis-ci.org/noise2/quadrotor-sim).

## Quesions

1) Why on earth this is an error when I have a successful compile in my desktop? [i.e, what am i doing wrong?]
2) How to make my project pass the travis-ci?

---

### Edit

> Note that class `timer` has been included already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @nfranklin I have noticed what was the problem. For what it worth to solve the problem I had to install one of the latest boost version, I came up with following `travis.yml` script.

```
language: cpp

compiler:
  - g++

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
    - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    - boost-latest
    packages:
    - gcc-4.8
    - g++-4.8
    - libboost1.55-all-dev
    - cmake

install:
- if [ "$CXX" = "g++" ]; then export CXX="g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -DENABLE_REINFORCEMENT_LEARNING" CC="gcc-4.8"; fi

before_script:
  - mkdir build
  - cd build
  - cmake ..

script: make
```

Now it is all good :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies within the following step in your travis-ci config file:

```
install:
- if [ "$CXX" = "g++" ]; then export CXX="g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/boost -DENABLE_REINFORCEMENT_LEARNING" CC="gcc-4.8"; fi
```

`timer.hpp` is being included from boost (i.e. boost/timer.hpp) due to `-I/usr/include/boost` instead ofthe `timer.hpp` that you wrote.

You can remove the `-I/usr/include/boost` from that step .  `/usr/include` is automatically searched for headers by gcc and and so the boost headers that you include (e.g. #include ) will be found.

Comment: Yes I see where the problem is, but when i remove that `-I/usr/include/boost` the travis-ci now cannot find `<boost/heap/priority_queue.hpp>` that i have included, see https://travis-ci.org/noise2/quadrotor-sim

Comment: Looking at the travis-ci build log, version 1.46 of boost is used;  `heap` is added in 1.49

Comment: https://github.com/travis-ci-tester/travis-test-boost might help.  Looks like they are testing the different versions of boost with travis-ci (as well as using cmake)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the boost's version, I didn't notice. :)